# FME Spatial Join One to Many

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, fme-form, fme-transformer

I am relatively new to FME and have been attempting to carry out my usual ArcMap tasks in FME instead.

One tool that I use frequently in ArcMap is Spatial Join, specifically with the One to Many join operation.

I thought that I had successfully recreated this in FME using the SpatialFilter transformer, with the following settings:

[image: FME Spatial Filter]

However, I realised after using it, that if I have multiple filters intersecting multiple candidates, it is only returning the candidate for one of them.
For example, if "A road intersects with A zone", and "B road intersects with A zone", the transformer only returns "A road in A zone", while "B road" has no merged attribute data.

I then tried using the AreaOnAreaOverlayer transformer, but this gives information for every feature and takes about 30 minutes to run, in comparison to the Spatial Filter which took about 2 minutes.  I think I must not have the AreaOnAreaOverlayer set up correctly.

[image: AreaOnAreaOverlayer]

My question is which transformer I should be using in FME to recreate the SpatialJoin tool in Arcmap, specifically with the one to many join operation.

Comment: There is a chart here depending on your source data https://community.safe.com/s/article/performing-spatial-joins-and-merges +FeatureJoiner would do 1:M https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/featurejoiner.htm

Comment: @Mapperz I'm hoping to join based on geometry rather than attributes, not sure if the FeatureJoiner works for this?

Comment: Have a look at the [spatial relator][http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/spatialrelator.htm]. It will determine if features have a relationship with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the SpatialFilter isn't quite right here. Yes, it merges information, but only 1 piece, because it's only trying to determine whether a feature overlaps. It's a yes/no result really. For example, I have parks and cycle paths and want to identify which paths pass through a park:

[image]

This works fine. I know that 19 of 39 paths pass through a park. FME only tells me the first park it matches because at that point the test is done (*yes*, it's a match).

There is a better chart for deciding on the right transformer, and it's this one:

[image]

...from [this page on the knowledgebase](https://community.safe.com/s/article/performing-spatial-joins-and-merges).

I wouldn't use an overlayer transformer because they're designed to actually cut the data where it overlaps. In this scenario I would use the SpatialRelator. It works like the SpatialFilter, but it continues and tests for a match against all features.

[image]

The key transformer parameter is the Generate List option. With this I get a list (a specific FME data type) that records all the parks that a cycle path passes through:

[image]

It even tells me the type of relationship if important.

So what you can do with that list is put it into a comma-separated value (ListConcatenator) or create a separate record for each list element (ListExploder) or do all sorts of other things (use a List* transformer or AttributeManager - for example).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Spatial Relator and List Exploder had the result I was looking for.